# wlan0 is missing

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, network-manager

My laptop wlan0 missing after `apt-get upgrade`. It works well before. `ifconfig` only lists `lo` and `eth0` now. `iwconfig` give `no wireless extension` error.

```
$ iwconfig
lo     no wireless extensions.
eth0   no wireless extensions.
```

I can see the Network controller of wlan is "Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG" by the command `lspci -nn`, I have already tried `rfkill unblock all` with no luck. `ifconfig wlan0 up` returns `wlan0: Error while getting interface flags: no such device` error. My Ubuntu is 14.04. Please help.

Update:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4220] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WM3B2300BG Mini-PCI Card [8086:2701]
06:07.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8319 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev10)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? What kernel version `uname -r`?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS, `uname -r` returns `3.13.0-58-generic`

Comment: Is there any informative clue when you load the driver? `sudo modprobe ipw2200` and then: `dmesg | grep ipw` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: `sudo modprobe ipw2200` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module ipw2200 not found.` `dmesg | grep ipw` returns nothing. I don't know, the driver works before, Does this mean I should reinstall the driver? How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to upgrade kernel. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot after installation finishes.

But you have to be connected to internet by wire or a USB dongle.

If it is not easy, you can try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Ha, the kernel hacker :)